# Alarm just wont get called

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I am calling a Alarm from a service `ScheduleAdvanceBookingService` to call another service `SendRequestAdvanceBookingService` at a predetermined time.

Manifest file has

```
    <service
        android:name=".ScheduleAdvanceBookingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <service
        android:name=".SendRequestAdvanceBookingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NOTIFY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

My calling code has

```
public class ScheduleAdvanceBookingService extends IntentService {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this,
            SendRequestAdvanceBookingService.class);
    Date startTime = (Date) intent.getSerializableExtra("startTime");
    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    newIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.NOTIFY");

    autoBookingAlarm = (AlarmManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    autoBookingPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, newIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(startTime);
    long alarmCallTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    autoBookingAlarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCallTime,
            autoBookingPendingIntent);
    Log.d("Taxeeta", "Scheduled a Auto Advance Booking @"
            + cal.getTime().toLocaleString());
```

My future alarm'ed Service is

```
public class SendRequestAdvanceBookingService extends Service {


public SendRequestAdvanceBookingService() {
    super();
    handler = new Handler();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("Taxeeta", "Start - SEND REQUEST.");
```

Debug statement to check the date

> 08-20 13:40:14.008: D/Taxeeta(31578): Scheduled a Auto Advance Booking @20 Aug 2014 13:41:37

What am I missing here ?

I have tried

1. Removing the intent-fiter and the addAction, still wont fire
2. Using startTime directly instead of using `cal.setTime(startTime) cal.getTimeInMilli()`

Comment: How do you call the service? Where is code for alarm?

Comment: try with removing `newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Comment: And `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"` is useless for a service.

Comment: Nope, removing FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK did not work

Comment: Check with your date instance, if you are getting the correct date from intent or not.

Comment: Date is fine, I have edited the question to reflect that

Comment: On which Android version are you testing it?

Comment: Testing on NokiaX 4.0

Answer (score 0):

The fix was simple and non documented anywhere.

I ran `./adb shell dumpsys alarm > ~/dump.txt` and searched for my alarms on my device. I found many pending alarms on the device for my app. This prompted me to clean up, and a Force Close from Settings->Application->MyApp->Force Close, cleaned up the alarms.

Then I ran my app, and it worked. Only after a while I realized that phones that did not have the app running earlier worked well, and that hinted me to the cleanup again.

So all I needed to do was

```
autoBookingAlarm.cancle(autoBookingPendingIntent);
```

before the

```
autoBookingAlarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCallTime,
        autoBookingPendingIntent);
```

This will cancel previous alarms before scheduling a new one.